# The entity type 'List<int>' requires a primary key to be defined. But it is defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to the Entity Framework and I'm having problems with properly defining relationships.

I have a `Student` class, and a `Course` class and it's supposed to me a many to many relationship. A student can do one or more courses and a course can be done by one or more students. But when I try to run the command `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` to create the initial migration, I get the error: `The entity type 'List<int>' requires a primary key to be defined`.
Here is the `Student` class

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Advisment.Models
{
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MajorId { get; set; }

    public int AdvisorId { get; set; }

    public List <int> CompletedCourses { get; set; }//List of courses done by student

    public ICollection <Course> Courses { get; set; }//Reference the Course class

    public Advisor Advisor { get; set; }

    public Major Major { get; set; }
    
}
}
```

And here is the the `Course` class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Advisment.Models
{
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public int MajorId { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection <Student> Students { get; set; }//Store student objects

    public Major Major { get; set; }
}
}
```

From my understanding the ICollection(s) is used to reference the classes, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Comment: You can use [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#collections-of-primitives)

Comment: You must use a Value Converter if you want to store the `List<int>` in one column.

Comment: Probably you should use the [Join entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration) with an additional `bool Completed` column.

Answer (score 1):

You should Add a third class which should be a bridge between student and courses. Because relationship between Student and Courses are many to many.

Consider this class :

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Course { get; set; }
    public char Grade {get; set; }
}
```

Change your student class to be like this

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MajorId { get; set; }

    public int AdvisorId { get; set; }

    public ICollection <Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }//Reference the Enrollment class

    public Advisor Advisor { get; set; }

    public Major Major { get; set; }
    
}
```

and `Course` class to be like this :

```
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public int MajorId { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection <Enrollment> Enrollments{ get; set; }//Store student objects

    public Major Major { get; set; }
}
```

In Fluent Api, you need to setup the relationship of the bridge Enrollments table like this :

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>()
        .HasKey(c => new { c.CourseId, c.StudentId});

    modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Student)
                .WithMany(s => s.Enrollments)
                .HasForeignKey(h => h.StudentId)
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Course)
                .WithMany(j => j.Courses)
                .HasForeignKey(h => h.CourseId)
                .IsRequired();
```

To retrieve all the courses that the student take, you can use this method

```
context.Students.Include(s => s.Enrollments).ThenInclude(e => e.Course).ToList();
```

Comment: yes I've decided to create a bridge class because I personally don't see another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hello In order to create relationships between tables you will need to add a Foreign Key which is the primary key in the table you try to connect.

So you need to the table/class that you want to the Foreign Key from
which you did in the Course List and implemented the many to many
relationships. So now all you have to do is to add the foreign key to students class

for example :

```cs
public int CourseId { get; set; }
```

Also add Primary Key `[Key]` to your student.

Comment: so do I have to add both `public List <string> CompletedCourses { get; set; }.        
public int CourseId { get; set; }` if so I'm still getting the error.

Comment: You should change the string in CompletedCourses to an int as it shown at your code and , add [Key] to your Students as well